# C++: syntax for accessing member struct from pointer to class

Tags: c++, struct, member

I'm trying to access a member structs variables, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. 
The two compile errors pr. access are:
error C2274: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator
error C2228: left of '.otherdata' must have class/struct/union
I have tried various changes, but none successful.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class Foo{
public:
    struct Bar{
        int otherdata;
    };
    int somedata;
};

int main(){
    Foo foo;
    foo.Bar.otherdata = 5;

    cout << foo.Bar.otherdata;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You only define a struct there, not allocate one. Try this:

```
class Foo{
public:
    struct Bar{
        int otherdata;
    } mybar;
    int somedata;
};

int main(){
    Foo foo;
    foo.mybar.otherdata = 5;

    cout << foo.mybar.otherdata;

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to reuse the struct in other classes, you can also define the struct outside:

```
struct Bar {
  int otherdata;
};

class Foo {
public:
    Bar mybar;
    int somedata;
}
```

Comment: The code is not precisely equivalent. In the first example, the name of the Bar struct is really Foo::Bar.

Answer (score 9):

`Bar` is inner structure defined inside `Foo`. Creation of `Foo` object does not implicitly create the `Bar`'s members. You need to explicitly create the object of Bar using `Foo::Bar` syntax.

```
Foo foo;
Foo::Bar fooBar;
fooBar.otherdata = 5;
cout << fooBar.otherdata;
```

Otherwise,

Create the Bar instance as member in `Foo` class.

```
class Foo{
public:
    struct Bar{
        int otherdata;
    };
    int somedata;
    Bar myBar;  //Now, Foo has Bar's instance as member

};

 Foo foo;
 foo.myBar.otherdata = 5;
```

Comment: I like this style better than the traditional C style "struct <Type> { } <Instance>".

Answer (score 5):

You create a nested structure, but you never create any instances of it within the class. You need to say  something like:

```
class Foo{
public:
    struct Bar{
        int otherdata;
    };
    Bar bar;
    int somedata;
};
```

You can then say:

```
foo.bar.otherdata = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only declaring Foo::Bar but you don't instantiate it (not sure if that's the correct terminology)

See here for usage:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    public:
    struct Bar
    {
        int otherdata;
    };
    Bar bar;
    int somedata;
};

int main(){
    Foo::Bar bar;
    bar.otherdata = 6;
    cout << bar.otherdata << endl;

    Foo foo;
    //foo.Bar.otherdata = 5;
    foo.bar.otherdata = 5;

    //cout << foo.Bar.otherdata;
    cout << foo.bar.otherdata << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Bar{
        int otherdata;
    };
```

Here you have just defined a structure but not created any object of it. Hence when you say `foo.Bar.otherdata = 5;` it is compiler error. Create a object of struct Bar like `Bar m_bar;` and then use `Foo.m_bar.otherdata = 5;`