# How use pointer to access variables of public struct

Tags: pointers, c++11, struct

I have a pointer to a class and I'm trying to use it to access the class' public struct.  I've looked at [access member var using ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107672/how-to-gain-access-to-member-variables-of-a-class-using-void-pointer-but-not-obj), as well as [access memb struct from ptr class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915106/c-syntax-for-accessing-member-struct-from-pointer-to-class), but when you look at the links, it's not what I'm trying to do.

I'm having trouble doing something that will build.  The examples in the code are without pointers, but I have a pointer to IFM to work with.  Does anyone know how to use the pointer (to IFM) to access the public struct (in IFM)?

```
//snippet of code that is trying to access struct in IFM:
const IFM *pJunk = rData1.getM(); //this is fine
pJunk->JunkStruct::Junk.xs; //this doesn't work

The struct in IFM.h:
class IFM final : public IFO
{
public:
    typedef struct JunkStruct
    {
        JunkStruct() = default;
        ~JunkStruct() = default;
        JunkStruct(const IFM::JunkStruct&) = default;
        JunkStruct(const double& first, const double& second, const double& third, const double& fourth, const double& fifth, const double& sixth) :
xs(first), ysk(second), xsk(third), ys(fourth), x(fifth), y(sixth)
            {}
        IFM::JunkStruct& operator=(const IFM::JunkStruct&) = default;

        // Initialized        
        double xs = 1.0;
        double ys = 0.0;
        double xsk  = 0.0;
        double ysk  = 1.0;
        double x = 0.0;
        double y = 0.0;

    } Junk;


...
```

Comment: It's a very big code base.  rData1 is from a class that holds a string.  Suffice it to say that I obtained a valid pointer to IFM through rData1.getM().  There aren't any getters in IFM.  Just setters.  I'm pretty sure I should be able to access the public data in JunkStruct, but I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Note that the typedef (struct JunkName) introduces the alias Junk. Not an instance Junk. As would be the case without the typedef.

Comment: Nope.  It says Junk type name is not allowed.

Comment: Sorry, I read your code wrong.  I didn't see the typedef.  IFM is an empty class.  There's no member at all... post the rest of that class.  The prob what @CaptainGiraffe said.  Neither Junk nor JunkStruct is a member variable of IFM.

Comment: There is no public data in JunkStruct unless you have an instance if it. Unless there is a constructed member of type Junk or JunkStruct you can't access it via pJunk.

Comment: IFM has a private variable IFM::Junk m_junkStruct; There are no other variables.  There is no getter for m_junkStruct.

Comment: Then it is designed to be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OPs member is private. It is designed to be hidden. Nothing to see here.

The struct is just a type. If no members in IFM is of type JunkStruct there is no data there to be accessed. To use that inner type you can see this minimal example

```
struct Outer
{
    struct Inner{
        int innerMember;
    };
};

int main() {
    Outer::Inner inner;
    inner.innerMember = 4;
    std::cout << inner.innerMember << "\n";

    Outer outer;
    Outer* outerP = &outer;
    outer-> No access to innerMember, it does not exist.
}
```

If on the other hand, the struct would not be a typedef but just a struct, that definition would be akin to:

```
struct Outer
{
    struct Inner{
        int innerMember;
    };
    Inner outerMemberInner;  // 
};

int main() {
    Outer outer;
    Outer* outerP = &outer;
    outerP->outerMemberInner.innerMember = 4;
// this might be what you are looking for
    std::cout << outerP->outerMemberInner.innerMember;
}
```

With `Junk` as `outerMemberInner`.

The type JunkStruct aliased Junk belongs to the type IFM, not to IFM objects or pointer.

Comment: That's very different than my question.  I have a class Outer that has a struct Inner.  Plus I have a separate class that has a pointer to class Outer, but needs to access innerMember. pJunk->IFM::JunkStruct.x; doesn't work

Comment: @Michele, you can't touch private members without permission.  It's illegal.  If you really want to get that data, add a method called GetJunk() that returns &m_junkStruct.  otherwise, make m_junkStruct public (and have your other team members yell at you).

Comment: Thanks.  I had been hoping to access the data directly through the public struct, but I guess not because of the typedef.  I'm adding getJunk() now and it looks like it's going ok.  Hopefully team members won't be mad about that too....